# His raised but ____ voice

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I want to describe someone rasing his voice but trying to keep it at a proper level at the same time so that he doesn’t lose his manner, and also because he knows somewhere deep down that what he stands up for isn’t entirely a truth.

What would that voice be like?

his raised but ____ voice

I’m thinking of “his raised but managed / constrained voice”... Does any of them sound suitable and natural? What word would you guys suggest?

Comment: Frankly I'd probably look for something besides a participial adjective, and instead try convey the nuance with a verb or maybe an adverb. No matter what you plug into the blank, the sentence will lack elegance.

Comment: Given your recent posts, I'm assuming you're attempting a work of fiction. Your nuanced description of the heightened emotion of a character tempered by social convention and insecurity about what he is about to say adds suspense and reveals a good bit of character. I'm dying to know what he's going to say. A phrase such as "raised but x voice," however, makes me want to suggest you hire a professional editor. Don't be afraid of spending some narrative time describing the nuances you want read into the man's voice, then tell your readers what he wants to say. Such a strategy adds a good deal o

Answer (score 1):

Consider *measured*:

> **measured** *adjective*
>   1.1 (of speech or writing) carefully considered and restrained.
>   ‘He was the same old Riley, with the tender brown eyes and the soft and measured voice, impeccable dress, and perfect hair.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/measured)

This would communicate that although the voice was raised, the speaker was aware of reasonable limits and kept to them.

Comment: I think I prefer ***controlled*** or even ***moderated***, but *measured* is suitable too. Plus one.